# generation of multiscale linear structuring element in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-morphology

I need to generate linear flat structuring elements with various length, degree and width (for morphological image processing). I'm using the **strel** function, it has just length and degree as inputs. How i can specify various width to my linear SE in MATLAB code?

please help me
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `'arbitrary'` option instead of `'line'` and supply a matrix describing the shape of your structuring element as an input. `strel()` does not provide any options for varying the width of the structuring element if you choose it to be line, which is kind of intuitive since what we describe as line in geometry has constant width.

You can use `'line'` option as your starting point. Save the line to a variable:

```
line_elem = strel('line', length, deg);
```

`line_elem` is a matrix of 0s and 1s representing line - you can edit it to fit your purpose and then supply it to `strel()` using the `'arbitrary'` option. E.g. if you want the line to be 3 pixels wide instead of one, just add one pixel to the left and one pixel to the right of the cell whose value equals 1 in each row of the `line_elem`. If you want to vary width, just edit each row and change different number of pixels in each row. If you want to vary degree, you can try to generate several lines with different degrees and lengths using the above code, then glue them together and edit the rows of the resulting matrix afterwards if you want to change width as well.

Comment: Thank you KjMag. I used the `line` because it generates the various length and degree easily. unfortunately I don't know how I can define a linear SE with various length, widths and degrees in a matrix for `arbitrary` input. Can you help me please?

Comment: @  KjMag: Thank you very much. It was so helpful. I generated the multiwidth structuring elements, but it doesn' t affect the result of edge detection in my image. so, I forced use just  multilength and multiangle SE.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. If you used the information from my answer to generate these custom SEs, and you think I have answered your question, you may consider upvoting and accepting it.